# Android gridview to layout its child view according to dynamic number

Tags: android, android-gridview

Use the below code to make GridView. problem is if GridView has 4 child then it show first three in the First Row and fourth element in the second row. i want fourth element to fill the complete width of Second Row.

If GridView has 5 Child then then last two child to fill the complete width of second Row.
any suggestion?

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    > 
</GridView>
```

Child View layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:src="@drawable/android_logo" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:textSize="15px" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: have you tried android:layout_weight="1" in each element ?

Answer (score 1):

when you say to your gridView that you want a **columnWidth="100dp"** , it will take your device screen width size and divide it with 100dp ... then you declared **numColumns="auto_fit"** so it will fill fit them to screen size ... 
eg: screen size = 440dp ... 440/100 = 4 ... 4 rows can be in one line ... image then you have 5 elements in gridview ... so it will just put first four into first line and the fifth to second line ... so maybe in your case the best solution can be to hardcore say

```
 android:numColumns="2/3/4" (how many you want to, this number can be decided from screen width)
```

Comment: ok thanx.  but if android:numColumns="3" and elements are 4  then i want 4 element to fill the width of its Row

Comment: thats not that much you can do ... only thing is to check that you have only four elements to display (array that you pass to adapter) and then call **grid.setNumColumns(2)** ...

Comment: if grid.setNumColumns(3) then i want fourth element to fill the width of second row.